# Looping JSON into an array of JS objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I loop through my JSON array saving specific values to a global array of objects within javascript? This is what I've tried, that I though made sense

```
globalPlaylist[0] = [
    $.getJSON("<../php/get_all_data.php>", function(data){
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            { 
              title:data[i].title,
              artist:data[i].artist,
              mp3:data[i].dataPath,
              poster:data[i].image 
             },
       }
     });
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
globalArray = [];
$.getJSON("<../php/get_all_data.php>", function(data) {
  globalArray = data.map(cur => ({
    title: cur.title,
    artist: cur.artist,
    mp3: cur.dataPath,
    poster: cur.image
  }));
  console.log(globalArray)
});
```

`<../php/get_all_data.php>` should be correct url without `<` and `>`